# Retrieving a document from a href

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, drop-down-menu

I'm making a code for download information from a website. My problem consists of access to a Href in a drop down with submenus. I have tried many codes, but any of them works.

The references with getElementById or getElementsByClassName didn't work because the functions focus, click, selecteditems ="1" are not supported by this objects. The dropdown menu has the particularity of being managed first by a click and then by focussing them. After the first click over three points, it hovers a unique option named Export and approaching it hovers another three options. I need the last one named "Download associated deductions". This is the code of the specific tag.

```html
<a title="Download associated deductions" class="ajax" href="exportPaymentLineItems.lvp?requestUID=&amp;reportType=xls&amp;reportName=Payments and associated deductions&amp;ajax=true&amp;isDrillable=" target="_blank">
    <span class="prgx-icon excel-icon"></span> Download associated deductions
</a>
```

This is the code I have in VBA

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'...

IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("ajax").Click
```

Previous in HTML code, the first click to open the dropdown menu

```html
<a class="btn btn-dots-vertical" id="dLabel" role="button" aria-expanded="true" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Export</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menuright">

            <li><a title="Excel" href="supplierReport.lvp?requestUID=&amp;reportType=xls&amp;reportName=BasicClaimsPaymentReport" target="_blank"><span class="prgx-icon excel-icon"></span>Excel</a></li>
            <li><a title="CSV" href="supplierReport.lvp?requestUID=&amp;reportType=csv&amp;reportName=BasicClaimsPaymentReport" target="_blank"><span class="prgx-icon csv-icon"></span>CSV</a></li>
            <li><a title="PDF" href="supplierReport.lvp?requestUID=&amp;reportType=pdf&amp;reportName=BasicClaimsPaymentReport" target="_blank"><span class="prgx-icon pdf-icon"></span>PDF</a></li>

            'The one I need to click, download or copy to open in another explorer tab

            <li>
                <a title="Download associated deductions" class="ajax" href="exportPaymentLineItems.lvp?requestUID=&amp;reportType=xls&amp;reportName=Payments and associated deductions&amp;ajax=true&amp;isDrillable=" target="_blank">
                    <span class="prgx-icon excel-icon"></span> Download associated deductions
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In order to download the document I expect to click the right class, copy the Href and paste in a new explorer tab or just initiate the download with a query sector.

Answer (score 0):

Try an attribute selector

```
ie.document.querySelector("[title=Excel]").click

ie.document.querySelector("[title='Download associated deductions']").click
```

Your line:

```
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("ajax").Click
```

won't work if only because that method returns a collection. You would need an index e.g.

```
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("ajax")(0).Click
```

[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns a single node. The first match for the css selector passed to it between the ""

Comment: Thank you. It still doesn't work because of a run-time error '424' (Object required). Do you know to what object it refers to?

Comment: The second code ...("ajax")(0).Click has a run-time error '91' (Object variable or with block variable not set).

Comment: It refers to the object at the line marked by the error. Usually 1 of 3 things. 1) Timing - try adding Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0,0,3) before that line 2) the path is wrong - check element not inside parent frame or iframe 3) element doesn’t exist - check html

Comment: I verify it's an iframe. What can I do?

Comment: It is inside an iframe? Can you include the html for the iframe and your element inside it?